# Python regex split

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a field that can filter over some db columns. But I'm having trouble splitting the search string as I need:

I have this example:

```
import re
search = '   test "no splits234" this-splits   this_not_splits  asdf123  '
re.split(r'[\s]*[\W][\s]*', search.strip())
['test', 'no', 'splits234', 'this', 'splits', 'this_not_splits', 'asdf123']
```

Need this output:

```
['test', 'no splits234', 'this', 'splits', 'this_not_splits', 'asdf', '123']
```

Do not splits what is in quotes and splits text from numbers. How can I do this?

Comment: Don't name strings `str`.  It overrides a builtin name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findall` with this regex:

```
>>> search = '   test "no splits234" this-splits   this_not_splits  asdf123  '
>>> print re.findall(r'"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^\s-]+', search)
['test', '"no splits234"', 'this', 'splits', 'this_not_splits', 'asdf123']
```

RegEx Details:

- Expression `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"` matches string enclosed by double quotes **ignoring all escaped quotes**.
- If there is no quoted string then we simply match 1+ non-space, non-hyphen characters using `[^\s-]+`

If you want to avoid capturing quotes then use:

```
>>> print re.findall(r'(?<=")[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*(?=")|[^\s"-]+', search)
['test', 'no splits234', 'this', 'splits', 'this_not_splits', 'asdf123']
```

---

**UPDATE:**

OP has also shown last `asdf123` splitting into `asdf` and `123`. For that following regex may work:

```
>>> print re.findall(r'(?<=")[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*(?=")|\b[a-zA-Z]+(?=\d)|(?<=[a-zA-Z])\d+|[^\s"-]+', search)
['test', 'no splits234', 'this', 'splits', 'this_not_splits', 'asdf', '123']
```

Comment: Almost what I need ... But 'this-splits' should be divided.

Comment: Thanks! Have some way to split 'asdf' from '123' too?

Comment: `asdf123` is strange as there is no delimiter. You didn't clarify this in question.